# Spring security returns 401, On sending date as input to the rest controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsInfoService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private CustomLoginAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

        web.ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/api/user/authenticate/**")
        .antMatchers("/api/user/**")
        .antMatchers("/api/master/**")
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

   @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
       return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

   /* @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
    private static class GlobalSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
        @Override
        protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
            return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        }

    }*/

}
```

This is my spring security configuration in the application.
It works fine most of the scenarios, but not able to track one issue.

Whenever I call a web service with a date format spring security returns 401 error.

```
http://localhost:9190/nazouki/api/master/create
```

with input

```
{"orgId":"11","birthDate":"2020-04-20T20:00:00.000Z"}
```

without date it works fine.

Controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "master/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ResultDecorator createMaster(@RequestBody  TuMasterDto tuMasterDto){       handler.resolveResult(masterService.createMaster(tuMasterDto), OperationEnum.SAVE);
    }
```

Exception has been thrown from the CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint in the spring security.

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint.class);

    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response,
                         AuthenticationException ae) throws IOException, ServletException {

        log.info("Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access");
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Access Denied");

    }
}
```

Comment: can you share code for Controller and also exception?

Comment: @Lemmy question updated.

Answer (score 0):

We can't say for sure unless we also have a look at the `handler.resolveResult()` and the `masterService.createMaster()` methods.

My initial assumption would be that you have a `GlobalMethodSecurity` configuration on one or both of these methods (or a code path that is used by them), and since you `ignore` the security for the path `web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/master/**")`, there is no `SecurityContext` created and therefore you get that response.

As to why it behaves differently when you add the date than without, I'm not so sure myself. Maybe you have 2 implementations? something like this

```java
public void handleRequest(Dto dto) {
   if(dto.getDate() != null) {
      doSomethingWithTheDate(dto.getDate());
   }
   // handle normally
}

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
public void doSomethingWithTheDate(Date date) {
   ...
}
```